# How do I split a Wordpress title at the &ndash; in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, split

I am working on my Wordpress blog and its required to get the title of a post and split it at the "-". Thing is, its not working, because in the source its &ndash and when I look at the result on the website, its a "long minus" (–). Copying and pasting this long minus into some editor makes it a normal minus (-). I cant split at "-" nor at &ndash, but somehow it must be possible. When I created the article, I just typed "-" (minus), but somewhere it gets converted to – automatically.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it. I remember that I have meet the similar problem that when I paste code in my post the quote mark transform to an em-quad one when display to readers.

I found that is in /wp-include/formatting.php line 56 (wordpress ver 3.3.1), it defined some characters need to replace

```
$static_characters = array_merge( array('---', ' -- ', '--', ' - ', 'xn&#8211;', '...', '``', '\'\'', ' (tm)'), $cockney );
$static_replacements = array_merge( array($em_dash, ' ' . $em_dash . ' ', $en_dash, ' ' . $en_dash . ' ', 'xn--', '&#8230;', $opening_quote, $closing_quote, ' &#8482;'), $cockneyreplace );
```

and in line 85 it make an replacement

```
// This is not a tag, nor is the texturization disabled static strings
$curl = str_replace($static_characters, $static_replacements, $curl);
```

Comment: you type a normal minus in editor, before they were store in database they had been transformed. When the page was display php just give browser the coded form "&ndash", and the browser will display it a "-".

Comment: The browser displays a long minus (&ndash;), not a normal one (-).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string at the "-" character, basically you must replace "-" with a space.

Try this:

```
$string_to_be_stripped = "my-word-test";
$chars = array('-');
$new_string = str_replace($chars, ' ', $string_to_be_stripped);
echo $new_string;
```

These lines splits the string at the "-". For example, if you have my-word-test, it will echo "my word test". I hope it helps.

For more information about the str_replace function click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

If you want to do this in a WordPress style, try using [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter). I suggest placing these lines in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('the_title', function($title) { 

$string_to_be_stripped = $title;
$chars = array('-');
$new_string = str_replace($chars, ' ', $string_to_be_stripped);
return $new_string;

})
```

Now, everytime you use the_title in a loop, the title will be escaped.

Comment: I cant replace or split at the minus, because its not a minus ... whenever I use "-" or &ndash in PHP, its not splitting or replacing or whatever because its not finding that char. The problem is not the split functionality, the problem is at what char I should split because no char is working.

Comment: Where do I specify the $title param if I do it the wordpress way? Or can I add the above code like it is without further change?

Comment: You don't have to specify the $title param, the $title param is automatically loaded by Wordpress. Try the above code without further change.